# How do I trim spent flowers of Kalanchoe plants?

Tags: kalanchoe

I have two beautiful kalanchoe plants with white flowers. The leaves at the bottom. The flowers at top are beginning to be spent. some are still fine but if I remember correctly they were the last to bloom. What do I do with the spent flowers? Do I trim and if so where, so as not to damage these beautiful plants, or am I supposed to leave it alone and let nature take care of it. I am not the best with plants but I want them and love them very much. Just trying to do the very best for them.